# Geting an error while checking WCF Service in Web

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on WCF Service as RESTFUL to receive data from SQL but I am getting the error when I am going to check it on the web. The error is:

> {"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section.

This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."}

```
namespace SCUIVIT_Service
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        //[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getAll")]
        List<UserDetail> GetAllUsers();
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class UserDetail
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string userName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string motherName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string cnic { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace SCUIVIT_Service
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public List<UserDetail> GetAllUsers()
        {
            List<UserDetail> userList = new List<UserDetail>();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-*******\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=abcdefghijk;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM USER";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
                    UserDetail user = new UserDetail();
                    user.id = dt.Rows[i]["userId"].ToString();
                    user.userName = dt.Rows[i]["userName"].ToString();
                    user.motherName = dt.Rows[i]["userMotherName"].ToString();
                    user.cnic = dt.Rows[i]["userCnic"].ToString();
                    userList.Add(user);
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return userList;
        }
    }
}

using ServiceReference1;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client objService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            bindData();
        }
    }

    protected void bindData() {
        IList<UserDetail> objUserDetail = new List<UserDetail>();
        objUserDetail = objService.GetAllUsers();
        GridView1.DataSource = objUserDetail;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

> Error : System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, the Restful style WCF doesn’t generate service endpoint address by default on the client-side, nor do we invoke services through the client proxy class.
We could send an HTTP request directly to invocate the service. Just like below(request an Http-Get method).

```
//upload image
           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
           HttpContent content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(@"2.png"));
            Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync("http://10.157.18.36:8800/service1.svc/UploadStream", content));
```

We could also change the WCF to traditional soap web service by using **Basichttpbinding,** which enables us to call the service by using a proxy class.
Please refer to the below configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.